# How to get Ctrl+Shift combination for Excel macro shortcut?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I click "Record Macro", the record macro window only shows Ctrl + another key as the shortcut key. As we all know, most of the Ctrl+ are used by Windows and Excel for other important functions such as copy/paste/cut etc.

I can seem to find a way to get ctrl + shift + another key combination out. Is it some where in the settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you only need to hold the shift key pressed (sorry for germany descriptions).

Without shift:

[image]

With shift pressed:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In that dialog, just hold down the Shift key and type the letter you want to use.

For example, the dialog shows like this when you just type the letter "q"

[image]

But if you want to use Ctrl-Shift-q, just hold the Shift key while typing "q" and the dialog will change to

[image]

Your keyboard shortcut will be registered with Ctrl-Shift-q.

For non alpha characters, the keyboard layout will determine if the Shift key features in the keyboard shortcut. For example on a US keyboard, using

Ctrl-1

in combination with the Shift key will create

Ctrl-!